# No Set-Cookie header in showing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, header, axios

I am making an api call using axios from my react app. The api call returns a Set-Cookie header which appear to be working fine in firefox. However, I don't the Set-Cookie header in chrome at all. I tried googling around this issue but couldn't find any concrete answer. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

**Url in browser**
http://localhost:3000/checkout/5423568515 
**Url for api call**
http://localhost:8087/session/loginByUserName

Firefox
[Image showing Set-Cookie header in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vziIA.png)

Cookies are even set in browser
[Image showing cookies are set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YkBp.png)

Chrome: No Set-Cookie header is shown and cookies are not set
[Chrome with no Set-Cookie header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jioi.png)

Comment: I'm running into this too. Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I also have a similar issue. It doesn't happen consistently though. If I reboot my machine it works for a while, then just seems to stop. Also using ASP.NET core on the server if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am also running into this frustrating issue . The API sets a nonce cookie that is necessary for identification, I can see the cookie being set on firefox clearly , it does not appear in Chrome, but in both browsers it seems to be sending this cookie. With this and the mess that is breakpoints in Chrome , i am very close to leave Chrome for development

Comment: Same report: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736723/set-cookie-header-not-appearing-in-google-chrome Happens in Chrome v114 right now, Switched to Firefox to debug a critical session related issue,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug (or poorly thought out "feature") in Chrome.  You can verify that the cookie is being set by [capturing a NetLog](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details) of the transaction.  This gives you access to the exact, un-modified headers on each incoming and outgoing request, including (if you enable the relevant option) cookies and other credentials.

I'm currently running into this from the other end -- Chrome is sending session cookies but not showing the relevant header in the Network tab -- and was planning on putting together a small test case to submit a bug to their tracker.

Answer (score -1):

An ajax library will never drop headers from a response. What you see in the network tab is actually what the server is responding with. I suspect the server is not sending back that header because the cookies are already set. Try clearing the relevant cookies.

The following code will expire the cookie specified in `cookieName`. By setting it's expiry date to the past.

```
document.cookie = cookieName + "=something; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC;"
```

Comment: Tried this new approach to set cookie header for both deleting old cookies and creating new ones but now luck with it . These cookies are httpOnly cookies, I thought httpOnly are not available for modification only while trying to access them in browser. 

set-cookie 
WC_AUTHENTICATION_1568784168=1…8sMKVHr8%3D; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie 
WC_USERACTIVITY_1568784168=156…ktwrA%3D%3D; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie 
WC_USERACTIVITY_1569130113=; P…=Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
set-cookie 
WC_AUTHENTICATION_1569130113=;…=Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: I see. Try using an incognito window and seeing if the cookies get sent

Comment: This is incorrect. Dumping network logs with chrome://net-export and comparing to the response headers in the network tab shows differences for this type of issue

Comment: Might not respond to OPs question but the document.cookie thing was really useful to me.